# Change a cell array into a matrix in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

everyone, I have a cell array in MATLAB:

```
'AA->AA'    [ 9]    [1.8036]
'AA->AC'    [ 6]    [1.2024]
'AA->AG'    [13]    [2.6052]
'AA->AT'    [ 9]    [1.8036]
```

I want to change it into a matrix with the row names are 'AA->AA','AA->AC'.....ect,I tried cell2mat and it reminded me: All contents of the input cell array must be of the same data type. so anyone give me an idea.

Thanks.

Comment: Matrices cannot have strings in them. What do you want to accomplish? People can give you better ideas if you explain your aim.

Comment: The strings "AA->AA" can be a row name. Other columns can be a part of a matrix.

Comment: Will there be only one row named "AA->AA" ?

Comment: No, 'AA->AA', 'AA->AC','AA->AG', 'AA->AT' respectively.

Comment: Wouldn't it be possible to think in columns instead of rows? Then you could just use the `dataset`/`table` structure from your last question.

Comment: MATLAB is not like Excel - you don't 'name' rows in a number matrix. You can mix them in a cell array as you have already done or separate it out into a string array and a number array.

Comment: I don't have the time to give a good answer, so I am not posting, but you can use containers.Map.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`containers.Map`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/map-containers.html):

```
myData = containers.Map();
for ii=1:size( myCell, 1 )
    myData( myCell{ii,1} ) = [myCell{ii,:}];
end
```